# How can i make two different rows zero at a time in pandas?

Tags: pandas

```
ad.iloc[1 & 3]=1
ad
    0           1           2       3           4
0   1.000000    1.000000    1.00000 1.000000    1.000000
1   1.000000    1.000000    1.00000 1.000000    1.000000
2   0.000000    0.000000    0.00000 0.000000    0.000000
3   0.000000    0.000000    0.00000 0.000000    0.000000
4   0.143442    0.556144    0.86941 0.932034    0.16864
```

Explain this also please

Answer (score 0):

Use a list to select rows `[1, 3]`:

```
>>> df
          0         1         2         3         4
0  0.009261  0.086365  0.593328  0.720758  0.737400
1  0.524058  0.082033  0.878503  0.207533  0.604475
2  0.153760  0.550047  0.541319  0.820629  0.723249
3  0.748347  0.978250  0.873707  0.566690  0.818272
4  0.195021  0.132876  0.484904  0.792552  0.149720
```

```
df.iloc[[1, 3]] = 1
```

```
>>> df
          0         1         2         3         4
0  0.009261  0.086365  0.593328  0.720758  0.737400
1  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  # <- all 1
2  0.153760  0.550047  0.541319  0.820629  0.723249
3  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  # <- all 1
4  0.195021  0.132876  0.484904  0.792552  0.149720
```